# Docker can not find /app/entrypoint.sh: 4: ./wait-for-postgres.sh: not found

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

My OS is windows. Backend django, frontend React, database pgadmin. All containers runs but the backend cannot find the entrypoint, but it is indeed here. I try the instruction on stackoverflow with similar issues but none of them fix it. Any one can help me with this? I attached log file and related fields here.

```
/app/entrypoint.sh: 4: ./wait-for-postgres.sh: not found

51 static files copied to '/app/static', 142 post-processed.
No changes detected
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, auth, campaigns, cases, common, contacts, contenttypes, django_celery_beat, django_celery_results, django_ses, emails, events, invoices, leads, opportunity, planner, sessions, tasks, teams
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Installed 1 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Installed 1 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Installed 1 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
 
 -------------- celery@47bc8292147e v5.2.0b3 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-debian-11.5 2022-11-09 20:04:14
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         crm:0x7fa12453a080
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . accounts.tasks.send_email
  . accounts.tasks.send_email_to_assigned_user
  . accounts.tasks.send_scheduled_emails
  . campaigns.tasks.send_email
  . campaigns.tasks.send_email_to_subscribed_contact
  . cases.tasks.send_email_to_assigned_user
  . common.tasks.resend_activation_link_to_user
  . common.tasks.send_email_to_new_user
  . common.tasks.send_email_to_reset_password
  . common.tasks.send_email_user_delete
  . common.tasks.send_email_user_mentions
  . common.tasks.send_email_user_status
  . contacts.tasks.send_email_to_assigned_user
  . events.tasks.send_email
  . invoices.tasks.create_invoice_history
  . invoices.tasks.send_email
  . invoices.tasks.send_invoice_email
  . invoices.tasks.send_invoice_email_cancel
  . leads.tasks.create_lead_from_file
  . leads.tasks.send_email
  . leads.tasks.send_email_to_assigned_user
  . leads.tasks.send_lead_assigned_emails
  . leads.tasks.update_leads_cache
  . opportunity.tasks.send_email_to_assigned_user
  . send_scheduled_email_campaigns
  . teams.tasks.remove_users
  . teams.tasks.update_team_users

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:830: SecurityWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
absolutely not recommended!

Please specify a different user using the --uid option.

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

  uid=uid, euid=euid, gid=gid, egid=egid,
[2022-11-09 20:04:14,723: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis:6379//
[2022-11-09 20:04:14,736: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2022-11-09 20:04:15,759: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2022-11-09 20:04:15,773: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:204: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
            leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  leak, never use this setting in production environments!''')

[2022-11-09 20:04:15,773: INFO/MainProcess] celery@47bc8292147e ready.
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:830: SecurityWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
absolutely not recommended!

Please specify a different user using the --uid option.

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

  uid=uid, euid=euid, gid=gid, egid=egid,
[2022-11-09 20:04:15,793: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
```

Tried

1. change CRLF to LF
2. double quotes ./wait-for-postgres.sh
3. remove $PWD: in docker-compose valumes
4. change #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash

Comment: Docker won't accept any of the PNG files you've uploaded; can you [edit] the question to replace all of the images with plain text?  (You should almost never upload screen shots of terminal windows or IDEs as part of your SO questions.)  Also consider trying to reduce this to a [mcve] with only the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem; it seems like there's a lot going on here and maybe you could replicate the problem with only a single Compose service.

Comment: Thanks. I have deleted those images and left the log file from docker. Hope this time helps